# How to customize x-axis label interval in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, linegraph

I am currently using JFreeChart to display some data in a line graph. The labels on my x-axis (integers) are too dense, so I hope to display only the multiplies of 5 (1, 5, 10…). How can I achieve that?

[image: Here is my x-axis]

Comment: It looks like you're using a `CategoryAxis`; you may want a `NumberAxis`; more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20integer%20tick%20unit); if this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: After update, a [`NumberAxis`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html) will "automatically determine its range to fit the data" by default; resize the enclosing container to see the effect.

Comment: Thanks! The axis does rescale when I changed the size of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to trashgod. The `NumberAxis` does help in customizing the axis scale. I did use `CategoryChart` at first and the problem get solved when I switched to XYChart. Below is the snippet about using `NumberAxis` to change the x-axis scale.

```
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
XYPlot plot = lineChart.getXYPlot();
plot.setDomainAxis(xAxis);
```